# Is Ruby's `end` delimiter redundant?

Tags: ruby, syntax

Why do you need to write the `end` delimiter in Ruby? Can it not be interpreted from the indentation, like in Python or CoffeeScript?

```
class String
  COLORS.each do |color,code|
    define_method "in_#{color}" do
      "<span style=\"color: ##{code}\">#{self}</span>"
    end
  end
end
```

Would look much better to me as

```
class String
  COLORS.each do |color,code|
    define_method "in_#{color}" do
      "<span style=\"color: ##{code}\">#{self}</span>"
```

If not, will it be possible in the future or are there any workarounds? Is there any language that compiles into Ruby (like CoffeeScript compiles into JS)?

Comment: Wow, 4 answers after 4 minutes! Gratulation for the question ;)

Comment: @knut: it's a simple question :)

Comment: @knut There are 4 questions here! :) 1. Spaces vs indentation (enough answers); 2. will it be possible on future? (not!); 3. There are any workarounds? and 4. Is there any language that compiles into Ruby? (someone may want to make a conversor from indents to ends; maybe the OP?)

Comment: Google for parse.y famtour, and LOL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby spaces are not significant. So, one needs to clearly mark where block of code starts and ends.

If this looks like a syntactic overhead to you, then you should look at Python :) (*I don't like it for exactly this reason: significant spaces*)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is just the taste of the language designers (starting from [Matz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukihiro_Matsumoto)). Many people just don't like indentation-based languages. Given that, it's nevertheless funny that some of those (like HAML or Coffeescript) prove to be rather successful in the greater Ruby world.

Nevertheless, Ruby itself will probably never be indentation based. If you want to use a general purpose language with that feature, you should take a look at either Coffeescript (which compiles to Javascript) or Python.

Comment: I love HAML for everything *except* it's indentation-basis. I almost always put comments where the `end` would be because otherwise everything looks so unbalanced.

Comment: Some love it, some hate it. I was a Python programmer in my former life, so I have no problem with that :) (although I still prefer erb to haml)

Answer (score 2):

It's a language design choice. If you like space based block delimiters use Python.

Comment: I am aware of Python, hence I mentioned it in the question. I don't think this is going to be the deciding factor of which language to use. I was interested to use Sinatra for Ruby, and the only thing I am put off by is the excessive `end` delimiters (and maybe a couple of unconventional syntaxes). I am not looking for a language that does not use `end` delimiters, I am looking for a way to avoid it in Ruby.

Comment: @BillyMoon, you can use curly braces – `{` and `}` – instead of `do` ... `end`, but only _with blocks_. They can't be used with `def`, `class`, `module` and the like, which require a closing `end`.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that it's redundant, but currently the only way around it would be to use braces instead (I'm guessing you'll agree that this is even more horrible):

```
class String
  COLORS.each { |color,code|
    define_method "in_#{color}" {
      "<span style=\"color: ##{code}\">#{self}</span>" } }
end
```

Comment: agreed, but thanks for the thought

Answer (score 1):

It could be inferred from the indentation if Ruby paid attention to indentation.  Most popular languages today, with Python being a big exception, don't have semantically significant indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Some languages do exactly that (notably Haskell and Python) but the down-side is that it is much more awkward to normalize indentation like this as there's less redundant information. It also means that the use of tabs versus spaces would become a matter of significant holy war, as opposed to just personal preference (and discussion in the bar after work).